# Drawing waves in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

I'm currently transcribing my Chemistry notes into LaTeX ([GitHub](https://github.com/bemeurer/chemistry)) and I keep coming across wave drawings which really help with understanding, but which I do not know how to do in LaTeX. I could use static images and import as graphics, but I want to do it with something like Tikz, so as to not need to carry around files with the LaTeX source. Here is what I am attempting to draw:

[image: Wave with wavelength]
*Wave with wavelength*

[image: Wave with crests and troughs]
*Wave with crests and troughs*

[image: Waves interferring]
*Waves interferring*

How could I describe these in Tikz? Is there another package that perhaps makes this trivial?

Comment: Read this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64171/plotting-trigonometric-functions especially the second answer.  This will get you started.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have more possibilities how to start with drawing your illustration. For example with pure TikZ:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->]   (-1,0) -- ++ (4,0);
\draw[thick, red] plot[domain=0:2*pi, samples=30]  (\x/pi,{sin(\x r)}); 
\draw[densely dashed]   (0,0) -- + (0,1.5)      (2,0) -- + (0,1.5);
\draw[<->]      (0,1.3) -- node[above] {$\lambda$} + (2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

For other images, read chapter *22 Plots of Functions*, page 325 in TikZ and PGF manual.

For drawing of function is dedicated package `pgfplots`. By it the above images can be drawn as:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
 domain=0:2*pi,
samples=200,
no marks, grid,
xticklabels={0, $\frac{\pi}{4}$,  $\frac{\pi}{2}$,  $\frac{3\pi}{4}$, $\pi$,
                $\frac{5\pi}{4}$, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $\frac{7\pi}{2}$, 2$\pi$},
xtick={0, 0.7853,...,6.2832},
 ymax=1.5
                ]
\addplot {sin(deg(x))};                
\draw[<->]      (0,1.2) -- node[above] {$\lambda$} (6.2832,1.2);
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
From your comment below I guess that for third image in your question you like to obtain something like this:

[image]

Based on your code provided on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/bemeurer/242bc622cc0c27b0bcf3be4db4decdc9) the somehow optimized code is:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\pgfplotsset{
  axis lines=middle,
  axis line style={->},
  xmin=0,
  xmax=4.2*pi,
  xticklabels=empty,
  xtick=\empty,
  ymin=-1,
  ymax=1,
  yticklabels=empty,
  ytick=\empty,
  samples=200,
  domain=0:4*pi,
  every axis plot post/.append style={very thick},
  clip=false
             }% end of common axis set

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}% 1. plot
[yscale=0.5]
\addplot[red] {(sin(deg(x)))};
\node at (2*pi,-1.05) {\huge$+$};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}% 2. plot
[ yshift=-3cm, yscale=0.5]
\addplot[blue] {(sin(deg(x)))};
\node at (2*pi,-1.05) {\huge$=$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}% 3. plot
\addplot[purple] {(sin(deg(x)))};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Constructive interference}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill %%%% %%%% %%%% second image
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}% 1. plot
[yscale=0.5]
\addplot[red] {(sin(deg(x)))};
\node at (2*pi,-1.05) {\huge$+$};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}% 2. plot
[ yshift=-3cm,yscale=0.5]
\addplot[blue] {(sin(deg(x+pi)))};
\node at (2*pi,-1.05) {\huge$=$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}% 3. plot
\addplot[purple] {0};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Destructive interference}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! This should be enough to draw all of those, thank you!

Comment: when trying to draw the third image, I came across a bit of an issue, I can't seem to get rid of the double y-axis. Here is what I've done so far: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/bemeurer/242bc622cc0c27b0bcf3be4db4decdc9). How could I fix this?

Comment: @BernardoMeurer, I'm not sure, if I understand you correctly ... see addendum to my answer.